# Replacing notepad.exe with a new one

Tags: c#, notepad++

I'm working on a project that let's folks remove the old notepad from system32 and download a new better looking one like notepad++

```
string path = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\notepad.exe";
File.Delete(path);
```

I tried **Build --> Run as administrator** but it still shows this

Unhandled Exception: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: **Access to the path** 'C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe' **is denied**.

Thanks.

Comment: Permission issues aside, it would probably be better to rename the old notepad.exe file to something like OLD_notepad.exe so that the program or user can restore it easily.

Comment: I assume that windows integrity protection will detect the change and restore the original notepad executable because notepad and calc are popular targets for malware authors.

Comment: @Pikamander2 Thanks, Seems even renaming prompts the same issue

Comment: @Psi That makes sense, so it would not work??

Comment: it may work for a very short time until the windows integrity protection restores the original file. maybe the integrity protection prevents you from doing so even with admin permissions at all

Comment: I think that what you need is to change the "Open with" setting of all text based file types to Notepad++. However when you have Notepad++ installed it shall already do this for most text based file types. Removing a system build-in exe file is not a normal scenario.

Could you please elaborate more about why the project wants to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All / most files in `system32` are not owned by the user. And in fact, not even by the administrator. So even with admin rights, you cannot edit most files. This is a mechanism by windows to prevent malicious access to system files and if you find a way to circumvent that, then congrats, your virus scanner will hopefully sound the alarm and prevent it from happening. Or Windows will restore it with the next update / integrity scan. As a quick way to check whether a file is part of this protection mechanism, check if only the TrustedInstaller-Principal has write access to a file. If so, it is managed and protected by the OS. Either because it is part of the OS, part of an Update or part of a Windows-Feature (notepad). It might also include Windows-Store packages as well if I'm not mistaken.

The way to replace notepad is not by replacing the exe file, but changing the file association. To do so, you need to edit the registry to which you can get access using either user rights or admin rights.

In the `HKCR\`, first create a new Key with the name of your program, (notepad2 for example). Create a sub key `notepad2\DefaultIcon`and set the default value to an icon path to change the file icon for files using this app. Create the subkeys `shell\open\command` to define what the default double click action should be. In the Default Value enter the path to your program followed by `%1` to add the filename as an argument. Now find the `.txt` node (or any extension you want to automagically open with the new programm) and go to the `OpenWithProgIds` subkey. Remove the `AppX...` entry to prevent those files to be opened with notepad.exe and add a new entry of any type with the name of the first subkey you created (notepad2).

Here a local example how the `.tex`-extension gets associated with MikTex in my case. You can look into your own registry to see how other programs deal with this.

[image: Example program key]
[image: Example file Extension]

For your use case it would probably work to download & install notepad++ (or other notepad) into a separate location and then change the file association to point to the new notepad.

Comment: CShark, I didn't understand a lot so I felt like reading more about registry. And i found an easier & better option. Why not add the new notepad2 to the right click panel
And thanks, i will read more on how regedit works and try your method it seems clever

Comment: Edit: Isn't that what were you trying to explain? if yes it worked

Comment: Yes and no. You can do either. One replaces the double click option, the other offers a new alternative. Both have their use cases, they are both valid approaches depending on your goal. Once you understand how the registry works, you can also manipulate it directly from your code. Regedit is just a nice user interface to see how things are laid out. Kind of like a file with its path and using the Explorer for visual navigation.

Comment: With all due respect, I do not think that it is a good idea to manipulate the registry directly. It is a better way to modify the setting via system APIs, and the registry should be a black box to developer (e.g., if the registry structure changed in future Windows versions).

Comment: @victor6510 Agree halfway. Regedit is only for testing - how do you verify your intended changes otherwise? Everything else though? That's what the registry is for - proper system integration. Many of the Options are and should be a blackbox (e.g. Hardware configuration) but many are also well documented and intended to be altered. File associations, context menu entries and autorun entries are a prime example for this. And it is highly unlikely that the registry structure will ever change drastically. Many structures are the same since Win95...

Answer (score 4):

The message is correct, you don`t have access with user privileges to delete files in the windows folder You can check if user has admin rights with

```
WindowsPrincipal pricipal = new WindowsPrincipal(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()); 
bool hasAdminRight = pricipal.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator);
```

You can set the application as "needs Admin rights" in you app.manifest by adding this line:

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

Apart from that: deleting files in the windows directory might not be a good idea. Usually you set the other editor just as a standard app for the needed file extensions (*.txt etc)